# CSS3: "after" positioned image doesn't show

Tags: html, css

My goal (note the small grey circle under "BEFORE CLEANSING" and "AFTER CLEANSING"):

[image]

WIth this code I can only view a RED SQUARE, not the image (but in firebug I can view that image is properly loaded:

HTML:

```
<p class="before-after">Before Cleansing</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

CSS:

```
p.before-after:after{content:"";width:11px;height:11px;background:red url('/../images/template/small-circle.png') no-repeat top left fixed;display:block;margin:0 auto;}
```

My result:

[image]

Of course If I change background color to transparet, I see nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Post full HTML / CSS with links to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the first `/` from the image url:

```
p.before-after:after {
    content:"";
    width:11px;
    height:11px;
    background: red url('../images/template/small-circle.png') no-repeat top left fixed;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Edit:

Also remove `fixed` from the background properties.

Comment: This is not the error. Corrected the error, but image doesn't show (in firebug is loaded correctly)

Comment: Perfect for removing fixed!

Answer (score 0):

@Catalin is right, that might work better if you remove the `/`.

For your info, do you know you can achieve the same effect with **css only**? You can make a circle with css in your `p.before-after::after` class with the following code:

```
p.before-after::after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your shorthand notation of background property. Try this instead:

```
background: red url('../images/template/small-circle.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```